# Unable to build protobuf to go endpoint

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

using protobuf version 2.6.1 ( which i installed via homebrew)

I am trying to run

```
$ protoc --go_out=../cloud/ *.proto
```

I keep receiving this error.

```
$ protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
$ --go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

I have the protoc-gen-go installed in my go path. 
Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Try manually installing based on the instructions here: https://github.com/golang/protobuf `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}`. There may be something wrong with the homebrew install.

Comment: Reinstalled everything. still the same error. I switched over to ver 2.6.0 . Still the same error.

Comment: You say `protoc-gen-go` is in your "go path", but it needs to be in your shell path, i.e. one of the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. What happens if you just type `protoc-gen-go` at the command line? If it says "command not found" (or similar) then it's not in your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks @KentonVarda, you should submit that as an answer.

Comment: OK, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`protoc-gen-go` needs to be in your *shell* path, i.e. one of the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable, which is different from the Go path. You can test this by simply typing `protoc-gen-go` at the command line: If it says "command not found" (or similar) then it's not in your `PATH`.

Comment: FYI, it should live at `$GOPATH/bin`. So do this: `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`

Comment: I have it in path and executable, but still report `Plugin failed with status code 1.`

Comment: @JiangYD, I had the same problem. Looks like protoc couldn't expand paths like ~/go/bin. Make sure you are using the complete directory in your PATH settings like /home/johndoe/go/bin instead of ~/go/bin.

Comment: I have tried all the above suggestions. Still it fails to work for me. FYI, protoc-gen-go is not there for me under `$GOPATH/bin/`

Comment: @darkdefender27 do you have GOPATH set? If not the default is $HOME/go/ . protoc seems to be ok expanding $HOME instead of ~ so for me adding $HOME/go/bin to my path worked.

Comment: I had the same issue but it was because GOPATH itself was not set within .bash_profile. So add the following line `export GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH)` above your `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` line inside the .bash_profile file.

Answer (score 31):

Using

```
$ go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}
```

is more safe than using

```
$ sudo apt-get install golang-goprotobuf-dev
```

Because the latest `protoc-gen-go` is using the lib `github.com/golang/protobuf/proto`, but `protoc-gen-go` in `apt-get` using the lib `code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto` which didn't exist now.

Answer (score 31):

1. You should properly define your `GO_PATH` - where your go packages
   live.
   In other words, `GO_PATH` is your go workspace. The `GO_PATH`
   should be `~/go`.
2. `protoc-gen-go` should be in your `PATH`. While `protoc-gen-go` lives in `$GO_PATH/bin` after you installed it.

---

Add these 2 important lines to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export GO_PATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:/$GO_PATH/bin
```

Then you need to start a new shell session or just type in this line:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Worked for me! :)

Comment: For **ZSH**
Add import statements in - `.zshrc` file
& run `$ source .zshrc`

Answer (score 13):

On Ubuntu 18.04, this is verified working to solve this issue:

`sudo apt-get install golang-goprotobuf-dev`

Comment: Tried this 1/28/2016 and this does not work anymore.  you can build `.pb.go` files, but not import them.

Comment: tried 3-3-2017, solved my issue same as OP, protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable

Answer (score 6):

I have Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS and installed `protoc` using

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
```

I have my GOPATH and GOBIN set correctly, but still when I did a 
`protoc --go_out=. <filename>`
I was getting

```
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

After reading bunch of places, was able to find that doing

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

was able to fix the issue. 
Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 4):

How I solved:

1. Add `$GOPATH/bin` to PATH by running
   `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`
2. add `export GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH)` above `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` line inside the `.bash_profile` file.
3. run `go get -u` for the required packages again.
4. run the code `protoc --go_out=../cloud/ *.proto` in your case.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem.

```
$ protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:pb/ *.proto
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

The solution as below:

Find the installation directory of `protoc-gen-go`, it must be in your `$PATH`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir
```

You'd better add it to your `.bash_profile`

```
echo $"export PATH=\$PATH:$(/path/to/dir)" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

then everything is ok.

Comment: Can you explain how did you find the installation directory for `protoc-gen-go`? FYI, protoc-gen-go is not there for me under `$GOPATH/bin/`

Comment: @darkdefender27  How did you install the `protoc-gen-go`?

Comment: Using `$ go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`
@pangpang

Answer (score 3):

What I did to solve this was:

copy protoc-gen-go from the go bin folder in go workspace to /usr/local/bin/

run your command as before in your case "protoc --go_out=../cloud/ *.proto"

Comment: I tried adding the PATH variables and restaring terminal or source to reload PATH variables. Copying the file fix all the stuff and generating code on ma Catalina is working now, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Directly from [grpc documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#prerequisites):

Go plugins for the protocol compiler:

Install the protocol compiler plugins for Go using the following commands:

```
$ export GO111MODULE=on  # Enable module mode
$ go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go \
         google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

Update your PATH so that the protoc compiler can find the plugins:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

Mby will help for somebody. I'm on Fedora 29.

When I installed Go I did:

```
echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/Go' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

So I have my GOPATH set up.
Next I do:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

And my `protoc` compiler work lika a charm.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS, I had installed just `protoc` with `brew install protobuf`.

So, to get the go code generator, I also needed to do `brew install protoc-gen-go`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Fedora, ensure that the package "protoc-gen-go" is installed, and it's binary is in your shel PATH.

$sudo dnf install protoc-gen-go -y

Answer (score 0):

If found this page because you get the error message in console when you run `proto`:

```
Protoc command not found
```

If you use linux then follow the instructions below:

1. download the protoc file here
   https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.19.4
   (i used to download the `protoc-3.19.4-linux-x86_64.zip` in my case.
2. extract the files in this folder `/home/your_username/.local
3. then you will have it like this: `/home/your_username/.local/bin/protoc`
4. Profit. this will work by typing just "protoc" in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8HMY.png)

I have installed protoc 3.20.0.
But I didn't get the tag for generating the code for Golang.
I have pasted the screenshot of all available tags.

Comment: 7 year old ticket.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that your path to `proton-gen-go` in your `PATH` variable is absolute (i.e. `/Users/me/go/bin` instead of `~/go/bin`.

Apparently `protoc` does not know how to expand `~`.

Answer (score -1):

On macOS:
The Same problem for me. First installed by Brew, could not force it to work, so I  went to: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/

uninstall all already installed versions and do as in the tutorial:

```
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.2
```

then:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"
```

to check go env GOPATH just run

```
go env
```

Please, before running the commands, check current versions.