# Error "protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable"

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protoc

I am trying to build a sample application with Go [gRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC), but I am unable to generate the code using "protoc"

I have installed the required libraries and Go packages using:

1. `go get -u google.golang.org/grpc`
2. `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`

I have tried setting the path as well, but no luck.

Sample "proto" file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package greet;
option go_package="greetpb";

service GreetService{}
```

Error message:

> "protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable 
> --go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1."

Comment: Can you add the exact command you are executing?

Comment: "protoc greet/greetpb/greet.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:." Folder structure: greet->greetpb-> greet.proto file

Comment: Read the documentation https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#prerequisites

Comment: For Mac Users: simply use `brew install protoc-gen-go` or another plugin like `brew install protoc-gen-go-grpc`,
thereafter probably got install in `/usr/local/Cellar/protoc-gen-go/version/bin`, add it permanently either on .zshrc (recommend) or .bash_history or .bash_profile.
check by `protoc-gen-go --version` simple!

Comment: @ArifMustafa This solved my issue well. Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I resolved it by following these steps:

Install the Go library using:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}
```

1. Run `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add:

   ```sh
   export GO_PATH=~/go
   export PATH=$PATH:/$GO_PATH/bin
   ```
3. Run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Reference: *[Unable to build protobuf to go endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099004/unable-to-build-protobuf-to-go-endpoint)*

Comment: This wouldn't work as the `protoc` compiler can't resolve `~`

Comment: As an aside, you really should be using `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`

Comment: @SoumasishGoswami can you explain why use .bashrc instead of .bash_profile?

Comment: @TannishaHill `.bash_profile` or better yet `.profile` is preferable for env vars which you export because it is usually only executed once, by login shells. `.bashrc` is executed by all interactive shells, so you end up just blithely reexporting the env vars everytime you manually launch a child shell.

Comment: `go: module github.com/golang/protobuf is deprecated: Use the "google.golang.org/protobuf" module instead.`
`go get: installing executables with 'go get' in module mode is deprecated.`

Comment: 'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
 To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version.
Here is a sample command to use:
```go install github.com/golang/protobuf/proto@latest github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go@latest```

Comment: if you are using `zsh` shell you have to change `.zshrc` file

Answer (score 61):

#### Go 1.17+

From https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation

> Starting in Go 1.17, installing executables with go get is deprecated. go install may be used instead.

**~/.bashrc**

```sh
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

**Install**

```
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
```

> go: downloading google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1

```
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
```

> go: downloading google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc v1.2.0
>
> go: downloading google.golang.org/grpc v1.44.0

**file.go**

```
protoc --go-grpc_out=. *.proto
```

**Environment**

- [Apple M1 Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1_Pro_and_M1_Max)
- Go version go1.17.8 darwin/arm64

Comment: In my case, it worked when I added this part 
`export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`

to ~/.bash_profile

Comment: This probably isn't what most people want.  Since most people are now using go mod, the appropriate option isn't to set GOPATH, but rather to use GOFLAGS=-mod=readonly go install {package} and then it will use GOPATH that's set in your go env.

Comment: always remember to re-run `source ~/.bashrc` in your terminal before spending hours cursing as to why the top voted answer doesn't work...

Comment: this guy is a hero

Comment: Setting the path to the one in the answer worked for me. The grpc docs say to set it to `export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"`, but that does NOT work for me.

Answer (score 55):

[Tannisha Hill indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700860/protoc-gen-go-program-not-found-or-is-not-executable/57731186#57731186) that the following package had to be added:

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
```

In my case, I also had to add this one:

```
sudo apt install golang-goprotobuf-dev
```

Comment: module github.com/golang/protobuf is deprecated: Use the "google.golang.org/protobuf" module instead

Comment: On what system and distribution (incl. versions)? Was it [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa)? Or something else?

Answer (score 35):

There are two ways to install the protobuf compiler. If you're on Ubuntu you can use this:

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
```

Then of course there's the standard way:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}
```

Here forward it's just adding the path. Assuming when you installed Go you did this,

```
echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/Go' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Now you can just extend this:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Strangely `protoc` can't expand `~`.

Comment: 'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
 To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version
Here is a sample command to use:
```go install github.com/golang/protobuf/proto@latest github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go@latest```

Answer (score 19):

From the GitHub repository, this solution has worked for me.

The Go version is *go version go1.14.1 Linux/amd64*

Add this to `.bashrc` and source it.

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT:$GOPATH:$GOBIN
```

Ref.: *[protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable #795](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/795)*

Answer (score 10):

Make sure your GOBIN is set in the `PATH` variable. Otherwise, you may encounter this problem. Check `GOBIN` path by running `go env` and confirm `GOBIN` is not empty.

If it is empty then try like below

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto
```

Comment: Exactly, as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated) state: _"Set the $GOBIN environment variable to change the installation location. It must be in your $PATH for the protocol buffer compiler to find it."_

Answer (score 10):

Also try the official solution from [grpc.io documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#prerequisites).

Go plugins for the protocol compiler:

Install the protocol compiler plugins for Go using the following commands:

```
export GO111MODULE=on  # Enable module mode

go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go \
         google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

Update your PATH so that the protoc compiler can find the plugins:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use `go get` to download the following packages:

```
go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
go get google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

For *setting* `GOPATH` and `GOROOT`, follow the below procedure:

But, first, run `go env`.

If you see that the Go is not installed, you can install it via [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)). If you see the output, then your Go is installed. It shows you all the environments that are set and are not.

If you see empty for `GOPATH`:

Create any directory anywhere on your computer for Go projects in my case: ~/GO_PROJECTS then `export GOPATH=~/GO_PROJECTS`.

If you see empty for `GOROOT`:

Run `which go` (on my computer: /usr/local/bin/go)
then *edit* your `~/.zshrc` file to add the following line export like this `export GOROOT=/usr/local/go`.

You can also edit your `~/.zshrc` file to add the following line to set up the `GOPATH` and `GOROOT`:

If you have installed Go from the original pkg, download from https://golang.org/doc/install.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/dev/go-workspace
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

If you have installed Go using Homebrew.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/dev/go-workspace
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Save and exit your editor. Then, source your `~/.zshrc`.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: But only on Mac (since [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) is mentioned)? What version of macOS was it tried on?

Answer (score 4):

I tried multiple solutions, but at the end I found out that Go environment variables are the actual culprits for this.

If you are on Linux, add these variables in your [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) or [.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file.

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT:$GOPATH:$GOBIN
```

And don't forget to source it after editing (e.g., `$source ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Worked for me once I had added `/home/username/go` and `/home/username/go/bin` to `PATH` (Go 1.16). It did not seem to make a difference whether env variables `$GOPATH` and `$GOBIN` are set or not (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
```

Step 2:

```
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.26
```

Step 3:

```
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.1
```

Update your PATH so that the *protoc* compiler can find the plugins:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the other responses address path issues, but if it's not installed, you can install it using the following command:

```
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go` in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) terminal, and if Visual Studio Code doesn't find $GOPATH and $GOBIN, it will install the package at the default user's home directory /home/$username/go{/bin}

The solution is to move all files in the *bin* and *pkg* folders to your current `go` path (/usr/local/go{/bin}). The `go` path is the one which contains the `go` file in the bin folder.
And add this line to the end of the [.bashrc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example):

```
export GOPATH=/usr/local/go:$PATH
export GOBIN=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
```

Then reboot the computer.

Answer (score 1):

After installing Go, use go get to download the following packages:

$ go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go

$ go get google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this message is because Go cannot reach the executable. Go looks for ~/go/bin to find the executables when it is called. Let's check to see if your PATH variable has the executable. But first, let's look at the error.

> protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable

To solve this, we should first inspect to see if ~/go/bin is in our path.

```
echo $PATH
```

Inspect the result to see if ~/go/bin is in your path.

If not, let's add it to our path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/$GO_PATH/bin
```

Everything should work now if protoc-gen-go is installed.

If not, install protoc-gen-go.

```
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worked for me:

> check protoc-gen-go install on your system if it's not installed then install it on your system.
> For mac *

```bash
brew install protoc-gen-go
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is facing the same issue nowadays.

Install the Go library using

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}
```

Make sure the GOPATH variable is set. In my case I created a folder called gocode, but if your code is located in another folder you have to change it.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/gocode
export Path=$Path:$GOPATH/bin
```

After following these steps, I found another error protoc-gen-go failed :: The import path must contain at least one forward slash ('/') character. To solve this, change the path in the option

```
syntax = "proto3";

package greet;

option go_package="./greet/greetpb";

service GreetService{}
```

Answer (score 0):

NB: Switch to root privileges on your terminal and follow these steps. This got me out of the ditch

1. git clone https://github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro.git /usr/local/go/bin/src/github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro
2. cd src/github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro
3. go build
4. cp protoc-gen-micro /bin

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

None of above works for me. It turns out you have to go to this [page](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) and download the suitable file for your platform at unzip it into your GOPATH. For  example this protoc-21.5-osx-x86_64.zip for Intel macOS or this one for linux 64 bit protoc-21.5-linux-x86_64.zip

Answer (score 0):

For this was what worked

`export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"`