# protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable [protoc-gen-go is in PATH]

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto, protoc

I am trying to generate Go source code from *.proto* file through this command:

```
protoc greet/greetpb/greet.proto --go-grpc_out=plugins=grpc:.
```

and, this is the directory structure:

```
greet/greetpb/greet.proto
```

I have tried all the answers mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700860/protoc-gen-go-program-not-found-or-is-not-executable)
But, none of them seems to be working.

I have verified that `protoc-gen-go` is in PATH.
Still, I am getting this:

```
protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--go-grpc_out: protoc-gen-go-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Additional details:

```
Go Version: go version go1.14.6 darwin/amd64
protoc version: libprotoc 3.12.3
```

My .zshrc file:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT:$GOPATH:$GOBIN
```

Comment: Try to add the option `-I=. -I=$GOPATH/src`. `-I` Specify the directory in which to search for imports.

Comment: I tried this ```protoc -I=. -I=absolute/path/to/dir/containting/proto/ greet/greetpb/greet.proto --go-grpc_out=plugins=grpc:.```, still getting the same error

@Зелёный What are imports here?

Comment: You can try this command `go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc` and set `--go-grpc_out=.`

Comment: _/\\_ this worked! Would you mind explaining the difference between the two commands?

Comment: To be honest I dont know, the `out` suffix looks like an option for the output path in this case the current directory `.`.

Comment: The `protoc-gen-go` and `protoc-gen-go-grpc` are two different `protoc` plugins. While the former generates Go code for protobuf message definitions, the latter generates Go code for service definitions.