# 'protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable', despite all the efforts

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protoc

I'm trying to run makefile command 'gen' from this project https://github.com/penthaapatel/grpcblog. The command is: `protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative blog/blog.proto` However I get an error:

```
protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable
--go-grpc_out: protoc-gen-go-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
make: *** [/home/deckard/go/src/grpcblog/Makefile:2: gen] Error 1
```

I use Ubuntu 20.04? Golang-1.13.8 with $GOROOT=`/usr/lib/go-1.13` and $GOPATH=`/home/deckard/go` ($HOME is `/home/deckard`). Protoc is `libprotoc v.3.6.1.`. I installed protobuf-compiler both with:

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
```

and

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}
```

There's a folder `/home/deckard/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf` and `/home/deckard/go/src/google.golang.org/protobuf` with `/home/deckard/go/src/google.golang.org/protobuf`, with, I guess, everything i need.
My bashrc configurations (tried few methods, so things overlap each other):

```
export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.13
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT:$GOPATH:$GOBIN
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export GO_PATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:/$GO_PATH/bin
```

So i tried solutions from here: [protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700860/protoc-gen-go-program-not-found-or-is-not-executable), but none of them helped me. Any clue would be helpful, because I stuck and am very tired.

UPDATE: `ls -l /home/deckard/go/bin/protoc-gen-go-grpc` shows `rwxrwxr-x 1 deckard deckard 7970222 мая  1 14:55 /home/deckard/go/bin/protoc-gen-go-grpc`, and `printenv PATH` returns `/home/deckard/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/deckard/.dotnet/tools:/usr/lib/go-1.13:/home/deckard/go:/home/deckard/go/bin:/home/deckard/go/bin://home/deckard/go/bin`

UPDATE: `which protoc` returns `/usr/bin/protoc` (tried to install it from precompiled binary to `/home/deckard/.local/bin/protoc`, didn't helped). In both cases `protoc-gen-go-grpc --version` returns `protoc-gen-go-grpc 1.1.0`. I also tried to copy everything from google.golang.org/protobuf to google.golang.org/protobuf, no result.

Comment: Please add the output from `ls -l /home/deckard/go/bin/protoc-gen-go-grpc` and `printenv PATH` to your question.

Comment: Thanks - your path has a few issues (duplicates, invalid path); I doubt that is the issue but probably worth tidying up. Please run `which protoc` (just in case snap version running) and `protoc-gen-go-grpc --version` (cant read the permissions due to language so this just confirms it runs). Note that you should consider moving from `github.com/golang/protobuf` to `google.golang.org/protobuf` (latest `protoc` may also be a worthwhile upgrade).

Comment: @Brits updated question and looks like I solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I deleted `github.com/golang/protobuf` folder, and seems like `google.golang.org/protobuf` has started indexing, and everything just started working.