# Unable to generate proto files

Tags: macos, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

When I try to generate a proto file using my Makefile command -
`protoc --proto_path=proto proto/*.proto --go_out=gen/` , I get this error -

```
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
```

When I run `which go`, I have this:

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

`which protoc` returns this -

```
/usr/local/bin/protoc
```

Here is how my `.zshrc` looks like:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

I have also installed the plugins

```
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.26
$ go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.1
```

Please else should I add my `.zshrc` to avoid this error?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67419012/11810946) help? (i.e. add `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use [buf](https://buf.build/) replace protoc, buf is more stable and easy to use without odd issues.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you still need to [install the plug-ins and add them to your path](https://docs.buf.build/tour/generate-go-code#install-plugins).